# Can we monitor AWS RDS PostgreSQL queries and stats using Newrelic?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, newrelic

I know that we can monitor the infrastructure and OS level metrics using Newrelic's integration with AWS. But how can we monitor the queries and DB level parameters using newrelic.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was requested but it's not implemented by new relic yet, which basically pulling rds performance insights to newrelic

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/add-rds-performance-insights-data-to-aws-integration/60821

Comment: But can we not use the default on host integration of newrelic to query the databases itself to collect the stats and expose them on a dashboard?